# Mysql 5.7 cannot start again

Tags: server, 18.04, mysql, connection, error-handling

For the first time in my life, I have Ubuntu, so I do not know much how to manage and what should I be looking for; I'm using version 18.04.
I installed MySQL 5.7, it worked great for a couple of days and suddenly it can't even restart, doesn't start again (with `service mysql start` or anything)...

Using `systemctl status mysql.service` I get:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-07-26 14:24:49 CEST; 
10min ago
Process: 3758 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid- 
file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited
Process: 3749 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre 
(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

јул 26 14:24:49 maax systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off 
time over, scheduling restart.
јул 26 14:24:49 maax systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled 
restart 
job, restart counter is at 5.
јул 26 14:24:49 maax systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
јул 26 14:24:49 maax systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request 
repeated too quickly.
јул 26 14:24:49 maax systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with 
result 'exit-code'.
јул 26 14:24:49 maax systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community 
Server.
```

and using `journalctl -xe` I get:

```
јул 26 14:24:49 maax systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled 
restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, 
as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
јул 26 14:24:49 maax systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
јул 26 14:24:49 maax systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request 
repeated too quickly.
јул 26 14:24:49 maax systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with 
result 'exit-code'.
јул 26 14:24:49 maax systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community 
Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
```

What should I do to fix this and continue to use Mysql every day normally?

my.cnf says error.log should be here : log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log, but I don't have that folder anymore, i don't know why, nothing was changed in my.cnf. Now i made again mysql folder but it's empty ofc.

Mysql works okay when I reinstall it, but after some time, it crushes again...

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43440534/mysql-doesn-start-at-all

The reason that service is not working is because "mysql.service: Start request 
repeated too quickly."

Could you please try with systemctl:

```
systemctl stop mysql.service
```

and after that:

```
systemctl start mysql.service
```

Comment: I edited the question, it works when i reinstall it, but then it crushes like this. And I can't use `start` or `restart` command :(